# Bot/app to find and then repost popular Twitter posts, based on particular niches?

Tags: twitter

I'm trying to find a bot/app that will find popular Twitter posts (based on particular niches, or inputted user handles), reword them (using AI), and then repost them, scheduled over a set time period.

Do any such bots/apps exist?

If not, are there any workarounds I could use to achieve the same thing?

Thanks in advance!

I've tried Google searching for such a bot/app, but haven't been able to find any that meet my requirements.

Comment: _"If not, are there any workarounds I could use to achieve the same thing?"_ You can write your own using the X (ex-Twitter) API. You'd need at least their _Basic_ access tier which costs $100/month.